# AttributeError in terminal

Tags: python-3.x

Please help

```
class ScrollingCredits:

    def __init__(self):

        self.load_credits('assignment.txt')

        (self.background, self.background_rect) = \
            load_image('starfield.gif', True)

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, FONT_SIZE)

        self.scroll_speed = SCROLL_SPEED

        self.scroll_pause = SCROLL_PAUSE

        self.end_wait = END_WAIT

        self.reset()

        def load_credits(self, filename):

            f = open(filename)

            credits = []

            while 1:

                line = f.readline()

                if not line:

                    break

            line = string.rstrip(line)

            credits.append(line)

            f.close()

            self.lines = credits
```

I am getting the error below

```
line 66, in __init__
    self.load_credits('assignment.txt')
AttributeError: 'ScrollingCredits' object has no attribute 'load_credits'
```

Im wondering if it may be the assignment.txt but im not 100% i googled it but I cannot seem to find a solution help would be much appreciated

Comment: The indention for `load_credits` is wrong

Comment: the function load_credits?

Answer (score 0):

As Wondercricket's comment suggests, you should decrease the indention of `load_credits`. The correct code is:

```py
class ScrollingCredits:

    def __init__(self):

        self.load_credits('assignment.txt')

        (self.background, self.background_rect) = \
            load_image('starfield.gif', True)

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, FONT_SIZE)

        self.scroll_speed = SCROLL_SPEED

        self.scroll_pause = SCROLL_PAUSE

        self.end_wait = END_WAIT

        self.reset()

    def load_credits(self, filename):

        f = open(filename)

        credits = []

        while 1:

            line = f.readline()

            if not line:

                break

        line = string.rstrip(line)

        credits.append(line)

        f.close()

        self.lines = credits
```